# error al querer borrar archivo de servidor godaddy

Tags: php, laravel-7, godaddy

he trabajado en laravel y uso laragon para manejo de DB y demás, todo funciona bien en mi pc, pero al subir al hosting de godaddy tengo problema al querer borrar archivos, cabe mencionar que puedo subirlos sin ningún problema, y los errores son los siguientes:
borrar: unlink(/home/srsb/tienda/public\evidencias/11115858media.XLS): No such file or directory, y si existe 100% seguro.
también al querer descargarlos, que repito, si funciona en mi pc en local, dice que no existe.
en definitiva el querer hacer algo con esos archivos, me dice que no puedo porque no existen.
Ayuda por favor

Comment: Casi seguro que se debe a la diagonal invertida \ en `... /public\evidencias/ ...`  En Windows podría funcionar, pero seguramente dará problemas en otros sistemas operativos.

Comment: muchas gracias, ese era el problema